# create Dynamic where in sql SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, where-clause

I am trying to create a stored that will some  values, one of the value is column name and a value. 

 I've tried the following code

```
create PROC SelectDynamic
@DateFrom DATETIME,
@DateTo DATETIME,
@ColumName NVARCHAR(50),
@ColumID INT
AS
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql=
'
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Ticket t 


WHERE t.TicketDate BETWEEN '+ @DateFrom +' AND' + @DateTo+' AND' + @ColumName +'='+ @ColumID

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
```

it give me this error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

 I am not a SQL expert, and it's me first dynamic sql statement 

can any one help

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the quotation marks when building a dynamic query.

Thus, your @SQL variable should be something like this

```
SET @Sql= 'SELECT * FROM Ticket t WHERE t.TicketDate BETWEEN ''' + CAST(@DateFrom AS NVARCHAR) + ''' AND ''' + CAST(@DateTo AS NVARCHAR) + ''' AND ' + @ColumName +  '=' + CAST(@ColumID AS NVARCHAR) + ''
```

Escaping is done by doubling the quotation marks.

You can do a `SELECT @SQL` after to test if your query has been built correctly.

Comment: @kirokaram Done, test it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think TicketDate column is a varchar field and you are storing dates as `13/10/2013` or `10/13/2013` in TicketDate field. if this is the case then you please tell use how are you are storing the TicketDate data then we can help you.

Comment: the column in table is datetime and allows null

Answer (score 0):

Change your where condition to this. Also print it before executing and correct the number `'` used here.

`WHERE t.TicketDate BETWEEN '''+ Convert(varchar,@DateFrom) +'''' AND''' + Convert(varchar,@DateTo)+'''' AND''' + @ColumName +''''='''+ Convert(varchar,@ColumID)+''''`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

declare @DateFrom DATETIME=getdate(),
        @DateTo DATETIME=getdate(),
        @ColumName NVARCHAR(50)='A',
        @ColumID INT=1

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql=
'
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Ticket t 


WHERE t.TicketDate BETWEEN '''+ convert(varchar,@DateFrom,110) +''' AND ''' + convert(varchar,@DateTo,110)+''' AND ' + @ColumName +'='+ convert(varchar,@ColumID)


EXEC (@Sql)
```

Which create the sql string as

```
SELECT      *  
FROM      Ticket t       
WHERE t.TicketDate BETWEEN '10-23-2013' AND '10-23-2013' AND A=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer doing manual substitutions and using parameters

```
SET @Sql='
    SELECT *
    FROM Ticket  
    WHERE TicketDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo 
          AND {ColumName} = @ColumID
'

SET @Sql = REPLACE(@Sql, '{ColumnName}', QUOTENAME(@ColumnName))

SET @Parameters = '
    @DateFrom AS datetime
   ,@DateTo AS datetime
   ,@ColumnID AS int
'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, @Parameters, @DateFrom, @DateTo, @ColumnID
```