# Check logical conditons stored as column values and output values using Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

This question is related to a similar question [which I came across on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31534248/2993606)

My question is a simplification of that problem.

Say I have a column in my table which contains logical conditions like below:

[image]

```
select '200 > 100'checkit, '' result into SomeTable
union
select '200 > 100', ''
union
select '123 > 100', ''
union
select '200 > 500', ''
union
select '1 > 10', ''
```

What I would like to do is to check these conditions and add a column in output which tells the condition is true or false.

So something like this:

**OUTPUT**

[image]

But I want it to do using `Dynamic SQL` if possible.

**EDIT**

One way to do it would be to go RBAR and use a cursor or a loop. Then store this column's value in some temporary variable. And then use dynamic sql to execute it.

Thing is I dont want to go row by row. I am looking for a better approach.

Comment: Is your data always integer > integer? Using dynamic SQL sounds strange if you don't have anything dynamic in your problem

Comment: @JamesZ - I just wanted to teach myself of thus nuance of dynamic sql so that in future i can use it if needed. This is not a real life scenario. Also as I said, one of the questions on SO triggered this thought process.

Comment: This isn't anything you would normally do in a database, so try to think more realistic scenarios

Comment: Ya probably nothing dynamic *in the data* per se. But I was thinking of something like ... `SELECT checkit, exec(checkit).....` only if the language allowed it.

Comment: I can and I would. Obviously this is far from ideal way of handling such a scenario. But I just wanted to know if there is a way to solve this.

Comment: Here is an example of the proper use for [**Dynamic SQL**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537166/create-dynamic-where-in-sql-sp)

Comment: Wow. Downvotes. Apparently I was wrong in thinking that SO allows absurd questions as long as their is effort involved. Can any downvoter care to comment the reason for downvoting apart from it not being "real life" enough?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - thanks. I am aware of how to achieve it using variables.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried with the help of CASE it is working for me
first we have to split value from '>' sign then we have to convert it in INT then we can comparison with the help of CASE

```
 CREATE TABLE checkit
    ([checkit] varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO checkit
    ([checkit])
VALUES
    ('10 > 100'),
    ('123 > 100'),
    ('200 > 100'),
    ('200 > 500')
;

SELECT checkit, SUBSTRING(checkit,1,CHARINDEX('>',checkit)-1),
SUBSTRING(checkit,CHARINDEX('>',checkit,0) + 1, LEN(checkit)-CHARINDEX('>',checkit,0)),
'IsTrue' =
    CASE 
    WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(checkit,1,CHARINDEX('>',checkit)-1) as int) > CAST(SUBSTRING(checkit,CHARINDEX('>',checkit,0) + 1, LEN(checkit)-CHARINDEX('>',checkit,0)) as int)
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
    END
FROM checkit
```

Comment: thanks for your effort! However I am looking for a solution involving dynamic sql.

Comment: ok you can go with @SouravA answer it is working or you can asign this answer in one nvarchar variable and concatenate i will make as string when i will free

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @dSQL nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @dSQL = COALESCE(@dSQL + ',', '') +
  '(''' + checkit + ''',CASE WHEN ' + checkit + ' THEN ''TRUE'' ELSE ''FALSE'' END)'
FROM checkit

SET @dSQL = 'SELECT * FROM (VALUES' + @dSQL + ') v(checkit,result)'

EXEC sp_executesql @dSQL
```

Here the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1f10be/16)

Comment: It threw error. Instead of executing it, I printed it. `SELECT * FROM (VALUES('1 > 10',1 > 10),('123 > 100',123 > 100),('200 > 100',200 > 100),('200 > 500',200 > 500))` Does this look ok to you?

Comment: Well I executed it on my system and it threw error. I would request you to take your time and give me a solution that works. I appreciate your effort though!